# Building opencv libraries doesn't generate "libopencv_java244.so"

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, 32bit-64bit, elf

I have been trying to get opencv to work in eclipse and I've been following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html) to try and get it to work in eclipse. I've gotten to the part where I create my .so libraries which is running `make -j8`. This works fine when I run it on a 32 bit linux system. I get all the necessary files I need but I get an exception in Eclipse when I try to run my program.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/joris/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_java246.so: /home/user/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_java246.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)

After looking up what this means, I discovered that the library is 32 bit but my jvm is 64 bit. I can't change the jvm that I'm using, so I need to build my native libraries in 64 bit.

I tried building the opencv libraries on a 64 bit system now, but I am unable to find the libopencv_java246.so file that I got from building it on a 32 bit system.

> user@BEL-8WF4XW1:~$ find /home/user/opencv/ -name *.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/mips/libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/mips/libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/mips/libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi/libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/armeabi/libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/x86/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/x86/libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/x86/libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/x86/libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
>
> /home/user/opencv/3rdparty/lib/x86/libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
>
> user@BEL-8WF4XW1:~$

I don't understand why it does work on the 32 bit system but not on the 64 bit system.
Can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do 2 things after installing open cv (I am on a 64 bit ubuntu system):

step 1:

it needed `/usr/local/lib` added tot the path to get it working.

(when missing a link, use `sudo locate <filename>` to find where it is)

this is not default, but can be added in `/etc/environment`: `gksudo gedit /etc/environment`

(you need a reboot after that)

step 2:

After this it might still not run. Use this to config links:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

I hope this will solve your issue (especially the last step might do the trick)